# Using AngularJS and Angular Translate how do you check if a string has been translated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-translate

How do you check if a string has a translated value? I'm using AngularJS and AngularTranslate.

I only want to display a value if it has a been translated. Angular Translate will show the untranslated string if no translation is available.

I started off doing this:

```
<div ng-if="question.text | translate != question.text">{{ question.text | translate }}</div>
```

But this doesn't work as the comparison happens before the translate filter has done it's work. (At least I think that is what happens).

What I ended up doing is:

```
  .filter('isTranslated', function(){
return function(translatedVal, originalVal){
  return (translatedVal === originalVal) ? false : true;
}
```

})

```
<div ng-if="question.text | translate | isTranslated:question.text">{{ question.text | translate }}</div>
```

This works fine but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Angular-translate also provides [a service](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service), so you could build your own filter around it:

```
.filter('myTranslate', function($translate){
   return function(key){
      var translation = $translate(key);
      if(translation==key) {
         return "";
      } else {
         return translation;
   }  
}
```

This will make your HTML much cleaner:

```
<div>{{ question.text | myTranslate }}</div>
```

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @delkant fixed the link

Comment: What if your translation and your key are actually the same?

Comment: @SebSob please have a look at my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Since some time now you can use [a custom error handler](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler)https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler to return an empty string if no translation is found.

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf="!(question.text | translate)"